# Do Mormons believe in the immortality of the soul?

Tags: lds, afterlife, immortality

Some scriptures refer to the soul as something that can die.

For example, Acts 3, verse 23:

> And it shall come to pass, that every soul, which will not hear that
>   prophet, shall be destroyed from among the people.

And Ezekiel 18, verse 4:

> Behold, all souls are mine; as the soul of the father, so also the
>   soul of the son is mine: the soul that sinneth, it shall die.

Some scriptures say that there is no life after death.

For example, Psalm 146, verses 3 and 4:

> Put not your trust in princes, nor in the son of man, in whom there is
>   no help. His breath goeth forth, he returneth to his earth; in that
>   very day his thoughts perish.

What is the LDS interpretation of these verses, according to their doctrine? Do Mormons believe that man has an immortal soul?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mormons believe the [soul/spirit](https://www.lds.org/topics/soul?lang=eng) is immortal/eternal. There are four phases of the soul:

1. Pre-earth life-soul before birth
2. Earth life-soul joined with physical body
3. Spirit world-after death soul goes to spirit paradise/prison
4. Resurrection-soul is reunited with perfect body forever

Onto the scriptures. [Acts 3:23](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/3.23?lang=eng#22) has a footnote on the word *destroyed* that points to two scriptures in Doctrine and Covenants, both saw basically the same thing so in [D&C 133:63](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/133.63?lang=eng#p62)

> 63 And upon them that hearken not to the voice of the Lord shall be fulfilled that which was written by the prophet Moses, that **they should be cut off from among the people.**

So *destroyed* in this context just means to be cut off from among God's people, or the saints.

Ezekiel 18:4 mentions the soul dying. Mormons don't believe death means destroying or the end, rather it means separation. [Physical death](https://www.lds.org/topics/death-physical?lang=eng) is the separation of spirit from body, but it isn't this definition used in this scripture. The other death is [spiritual death](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/death-spiritual), where when man sins he is separated from God's presence, which is the usage in Ezekiel 18:4. If a man [repents](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/repent-repentance.html?lang=eng&letter=R) he forsakes sin and turns back to God, and thus can overcome spiritual death.

Psalms 146:3-4 is referencing physical death and once the spirit leaves the body the body returns to the earth. The body no longer has a spirit and has no thought, the spirit still lives in the spirit world. [James 2:26](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/james/2.26?lang=eng#25) on the body being dead:

> 26 **For as the body without the spirit is dead**, so faith without works is dead also.

Also in Psalms 146 *His* and *he* refers to the physical body since it mentions `he returneth to the earth;` so the next line refers to the body losing it's thoughts, because the spirit has left it, not the spirit dying (being destroyed/ending).

From Answers to Gospel Questions Volume 4 page 183 by Joseph Fielding Smith (the question that is being asked is on [Ecclesiastes 9:4,5,10](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/eccl/9.4,5,10?lang=eng#3) and seems like a similar question to yours):

> ...the body is laid away in the grave peacefully and it knows nothing as to the affairs of a busy world....The death of the mortal body does not bring a death of the spirit.

Comment: It's also worth noting that e.g., Acts 3:23, we believe in the Second Death mentioned in Rev 2:11; 20:6-14; etc., and believe that death is a spiritual death, not that the spirit itself is destroyed, but permanent seperation from God and loss of all glory (Alma 12:16-32; Helaman 14:18-20; etc., those who die the Second Death can be thought of as "destroyed" in that all hope of exaltation are destroyed.